# Picasso load image on API 17 - Error HTTP 504

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I want to display a random image using Unsplash website with Picasso. However the image won't display on API 17 physical tablet. It does display on API 28 emulator.

How do I display images using Picasso on API 17 devices?

Picasso version:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

load image:

```
private const val RAND_IMAGE_URL:String = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617721042477-7c5c498e7dbf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=800"

// Load the random image
        val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_image)
        Picasso.get().load(RAND_IMAGE_URL)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_72)
                        .into(image, object : Callback {
                            override fun onSuccess() {
                                // successfully loaded
                                //  hide progress bar
                                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            }

                            override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                                // display error message
                                
                                Log.e(TAG, "error loading image", e)
                                //  hide progress bar
                                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            }

                        })
```

The error:

```
com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler$ResponseException: HTTP 504
        at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:51)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:219)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:354)
```

I tried solutions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430498/error-http-504-when-load-image-form-url-with-picasso-android-library), [this link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1896#issuecomment-697232550), and changing URL to http, but nothing worked. I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han) talking about some protocol change but I don't know what it means or if it's related.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han). It says to enable TLSv1.2 protocol by updating Android's security Provider through Google Play Services.

First add dependency to app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
```

Then

```
private fun updateAndroidSecurityProvider(callingActivity: Activity) {
        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this)
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
            // Thrown when Google Play Services is not installed, up-to-date, or enabled
            // Show dialog to allow users to install, update, or otherwise enable Google Play services.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), callingActivity, 0)
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
            Log.e("SecurityException", "Google Play Services not available.")
        }
    }
```

After creating and calling the function, I could display the image.